# HTML Target limit function to active window

Tags: html, href, target

So i got a question about the Target function in HTML

I got a link `<a href="red.html/variable(a,b,c,etc.)" target="red">RED</a>`
all it does is, it opens a new Tab to red.html/variable, if red.html is already open in a tab it targets this tab and opens the link in the existing tab. fine so far.
But i have some People who don't want to loose info they have filled in the red.html/variable A but still want to open red.html/variable B.
So i thought well just drag it out of the window and make this tab its own window so it shouldn't target that other window. I thought wrong and it doesn't work like this.

Is there a option how to force the Browser to use a function in just the active window (including tabs) but ignore other open windows?
Example:

> Window1: TAB(red, green, blue) open Link"brown" with function
> mentioned above --> open new tab"brown" Window2: Tab(brown, yellow)
> <-- tab brown is ignored by links from window1.

i do hope i was able to explain my problem and what i have in mind as targeted behaviour.
Any help is appreciated.

what i've tried:
just different Target Options and `rel=noopener`. Non worked

Comment: can't you just ***always*** open the link in a new tab regardless of which tab already has that url loaded? in that case it would be `target="_blank"`. Anyway the `target` strategy doesn't take into accout to which window the tabs belong to when looking for matches. Your need may require you to do something really convoluted involving euristics that will guess if such event (moving tab to a new window) ever happened). But it's far from being simple and maybe impossible

Comment: anyway I may have a suggestion being the furthest thing in my mind to address that problem: you have your page opening those links using unique targets; if you open a link twice, it will be reloaded on the same tab where it was opened the first time; but if you move that tab to a new window, since it's hard to understand such event occurred, you may add a button on the page (and inform the user about it) that when clicked, will change `window.name` detaching the browser context from the known `target` name so that clicking again the link on the main page won't reload that tab